# NCH Software buggered my IE new tab creation -- how to fix?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, malware, adware

I made the big mistake of installing video capture software from NCH and afterwards noticed that besides installing (and trying to install) all kinds of crap I didn't want, without asking (including, ironically, the Ask Toolbar), it attempted to change my IE homepage to something else.  I prevented this because Spybot notified me about what it was trying to do, and I denied permission for the registry change.

After this fiasco, I spent a good amount of time rooting NCH out of my machine, but one of its legacies was IE new tab creation.  Now, instead of creating a new tab with an "about: blank" in the address bar, it creates a new instance of Gmail!  Which is actually what I've set my browser's homepage to, but I want the "about: blank" back!

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Sorry to hear you had such a poor experience - NCH Software is taking the right steps for its users: [Toolbar Uninstall Instructions - Only in Older Versions of Software](http://www.nch.com.au/general/uninstall.html) ||||| [Is NCH Software Safe?](http://www.nch.com.au/software/safety-guarantee.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to **Tools** -> **Internet options**
2. Under **Tabs**, click on **Settings**
3. There's a setting called "When a new tab is opened, open:" which is currently probably set to "Your first home page"; change it to "A blank page"

[image]

Comment: Yes!  Thanks -- I'm a brilliant professional programmer by day, and a complete idiot sometimes when it comes to normal-person tools.